# Adding compilation symbol in Unity Il2Cpp build solution

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

Previously i used to add my compilation symbols at this location - project > properties > build > Conditional compilation symbols .
[.Net build compilation symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZBmt.png)

but Now after building a solution using IL2Cpp, i cant find the location to add the compilation symbols.
though i tried to add it at this location : [IL2Cpp build compilation symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws9Fp.png)
and even at : [IL2Cpp build compilation symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJzIt.png) this location

But still it doesn't work as expected, my code which closed under that compilation symbol doesn't executes.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to change conditional compilation symbols in Visual Studio when working with Unity projects.

Instead, do this in the *Unity editor*:

**Edit** > **Project Settings** > **Player** > **Other Settings** > **Scripting Define Symbols**